# access python module code

Tags: python, python-2.7, introspection

I am trying to access the code that is executed by a module when it is imported.

Visualizing the source or editing it is not the question here. I would like to know where those instructions are stored.

**Example**

*module.py*

```
def func():
    print 'func'

print 'module'
```

*Python console*

```
>>> import module
module
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(module)
Disassembly of func:
0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('func')
3 PRINT_ITEM          
4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
8 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dir(module)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'func']
```

Where can I find the `<function>` object, or the func_code or whatever which stores the `print 'module'` instruction?

Comment: @pokoli, that doesn't relate- this isn't a quine, it's trying to access bytecode.

Comment: `print 'module'` doesn't exist in any object. It is executed when the module is defined, but is not *part* of the module. There is a distinction between the file which contains the code that defines the module, and the `module` object that results from executing that file.

Comment: @chepner : Oh, ok thanks ! so if I want to go deeper, should I open a different question asking : How to hook the import builtin to get a trace of the code executed on import ? (I'm new to SO)

Comment: That sounds like a very good question to ask (a quick search for `__import__` didn't find anything related, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html)

dis.dis([bytesource])

Disassemble the bytesource object. bytesource can denote either a module, a class, a method, a function, or a code object. For a module, it disassembles all functions.

As module.py is a module, it's disassembling all functions in the module. As the "print 'module'" call is not in a function, it doesn't get disassembled.

EDIT:

To answer the actual question (sorry about that), as the statement is called when you import the module itself, I'm pretty sure that you can solve it as follows (though this is a bit horrible, as solutions go, and there's probably a better way to do it):

```
class importer():
    def import_module():
        import module
dis.dis(importer)
```

Which is a slight abuse of how dis works, but hey, it seems to work.

Comment: This answers the question *"why doesn't `dis.dis` show the `print` instruction"*, but **not** *"where can I find..."*.

Comment: Ok, so maybe dis.dis isn't the right tool for the job, but is there another wich would allow me to access this specific "print 'module'" instruction ? edit : as jonrsharpe said 20s before me

Comment: @jonrsharpe Any better?

Comment: Well it's not clear why you're wrapping the function in a class, and it never actually shows you the instruction to `PRINT_ITEM`.

Comment: @edit : I tried, and it doesn't seem to work. It just returns a very small bytecod with IMPORT_NAME 0 (module) in it. But maybe I'm doing it wrong..

Comment: Huh. I've wrapped it in a class because that makes dis disassemble the functions within the class, and it showed the instruction to print_item when I ran it. Something is rotten in the state of denmark...